# 404 error for file initiated by vendor.js while integrating Angular with django

Tags: python, django, angular

I get the following error message in browser console when I try to integrate my angular front end with django.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/another.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I believe I have configured static file settings in django correctly as it is able to locate all the other static files, ie `main.js`, `polyfills.js`, `vendor.js` etc.

This `assets/another.js` call initiated by vendor.js while other js files are called in index.html. I have all these files in the same static dir.

When I run `python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 assets/another.js` I get the following response -

```
Found 'assets/another.js' here:
  /home/path/to/project/server/static/assets/another.js
Looking in the following locations:
  /home/path/to/project/server/server/static
  /home/path/to/admin/static  # irrelevant in this case
```

Comment: Did you define another.js file in static folder in django?

Comment: Yes it is located in djangostaticfolder/assets/another.js . As you can see from the question description, django is able to locate this file when I run `python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 assets/another.js`. However it is not reflected in the browser.